# Problems creating Sankey diagrams using d3.js (2)

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

This is a continuation of my previous question "Problems creating Sankey diagrams using d3.js (1)"

Here I'm trying to follow the example posted by timelyprtfolio at http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html which uses packages igraph and rCharts to create a Sankey diagram template

[image]

The output from running the R script is

./rCharts_d3_sankey-gh-pages/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey/layouts/chart.html

and the resultant html is

```
<!--Attribution:
Mike Bostock https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/sankey
Mike Bostock http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/
-->

<script>
(function(){
var params = {{{ chartParams }}};

params.units ? units = " " + params.units : units = "";

//hard code these now but eventually make available
var formatNumber = d3.format("0,.0f"),    // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + units; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

if(params.labelFormat){
  formatNumber = d3.format(".2%");
}

var svg = d3.select('#' + params.id).append("svg")
    .attr("width", params.width)
    .attr("height", params.height);

var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(params.nodeWidth)
    .nodePadding(params.nodePadding)
    .layout(params.layout)
    .size([params.width,params.height]);

var path = sankey.link();

var data = params.data,
    links = [],
    nodes = [];

//get all source and target into nodes
//will reduce to unique in the next step
//also get links in object form
data.source.forEach(function (d, i) {
    nodes.push({ "name": data.source[i] });
    nodes.push({ "name": data.target[i] });
    links.push({ "source": data.source[i], "target": data.target[i], "value": +data.value[i] });
}); 

//now get nodes based on links data
//thanks Mike Bostock https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/pl297cFtIQk/Eso4q_eBu1IJ
//this handy little function returns only the distinct / unique nodes
nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
                .map(nodes));

//it appears d3 with force layout wants a numeric source and target
//so loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
links.forEach(function (d, i) {
    links[i].source = nodes.indexOf(links[i].source);
    links[i].target = nodes.indexOf(links[i].target);
});

//now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects rather than an array of strings
nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
    nodes[i] = { "name": d };
});

sankey
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .layout(params.layout);

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
  .sort(function (a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

link.append("title")
  .text(function (d) { return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function (d) { return d; })
  .on("dragstart", function () { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
  .on("drag", dragmove));

node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function (d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
.append("title")
  .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

node.append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function (d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
.filter(function (d) { return d.x < params.width / 2; })
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");

// the function for moving the nodes
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + (
                   d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(params.width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
                ) + "," + (
                   d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(params.height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
                ) + ")");
        sankey.relayout();
        link.attr("d", path);
  }
})();
</script>
```

This throws an error in the Javascript console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { timelyportfolio.html:8" which is referencing var params = {{{ chartParams }}};

Timelyportfolio isn't sure what might be going wrong but has made a couple of suggestions on how to improve the custom template pain

Again, any insights that would help me understand what's going wrong would be much appreciated

Many thanks

Julian

Answer (score 1):

I just now saw this.  Sorry to be so late.  The {{{ }}} is from the R package `whisker` based on the concept of [mustache templates](http://mustache.github.io/).  The {{{ chartParams }}} will be filled by the R variable when run through `rCharts`.  The html does not work standalone.